# Object of class DOMNodeList could not be converted to string

Tags: dom, xpath

I got the above error and tried to print out the object to see how I could access the data inside of it but it only echoed    DOMNodeList Object ( )

```
function dom() {
$url = "http://website.com/demo/try.html";
$contents = wp_remote_fopen($url);

$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($contents);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$result = $xpath->evaluate('/html/body/table[0]');
print_r($result);
    }
```

I'm using Wordpress, thus explains the wp_remote_fopen function.  I'm trying to echo the first table from $url

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yeah, `DOMXpath::query` returns are always a `DOMNodeList`, which is a bit of an odd object to deal with. You basically have to iterate over it, or just use `item()` to get a single item:

```
// There's actually something in the list
if($result->length > 0) {
  $node = $result->item(0);
  echo "{$node->nodeName} - {$node->nodeValue}";
} 
else {
  // empty result set
}
```

Or you can loop through the values:

```
foreach($result as $node) {
  echo "{$node->nodeName} - {$node->nodeValue}";
  // or you can just print out the the XML:
  // $dom->saveXML($node);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that really helped my understanding!

Answer (score 0):

Xpath starts the index with 1 not 0: `/html/body/table[1]`

Now it depends if you want to save the HTML of the matched node or if you want the text content of the node.

```
$html = <<<'HTML'
<html>
  <body>
    <p>Hello World</p>
  </body>
</html>
HTML;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

// iterate all matched nodes and save them as HTML to a buffer
$result = '';
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('/html/body/p[1]') as $p) {
  $result .= $dom->saveHtml($p);
}
var_dump($result);

// cast the first matched node to a string
var_dump(
  $xpath->evaluate('string(/html/body/p[1])')
);
```

Demo: https://eval.in/155592

```
string(18) "<p>Hello World</p>"
string(11) "Hello World"
```